# 24 bit ADC chip

Tags: pi-3

I am using my Raspberry pi 3 and I am wondering if there is actually a 24 bit ADC chip compatible with the pi? I am going to use that ADC with LVDT sensor to measure a distance of 10mm in good precision. I understand that noise will kick in and I can only achieve 18 bit accuracy from the link below. 
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=64503

Answer (score 2):

There's support for the ADAU1977 (Quad 24 bit ADC) in the 4.9 kernel. To use it get the pi kernel sources (https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux.git) check out the `rpi-4.9.y` branch and follow the build/install instructions (https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/kernel/building.md) then edit the `/boot/config.txt` file, removing `dtparam=audio=on` and adding `dtoverlay=adau1977-adc` then use `arecord` (or another audio app) to capture the samples.

Comment: Thank you for answering :) Hmmm once I am done with the installation of the kernel, which package should I use? Or I can just obtain the drivers of this ADC from the supplier ?

Comment: If you follow the instruction then `arecord -l` will show the ADC. It looks like support was added in kernel 4.4 (https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/pull/1454)